# Redis Sentinel - Delete keys

Tags: php, redis, sentinel, predis

while trying to implement sentinel on redis ( 1 master, 2 slaves), I have been unable to delete keys stored on it. If I remove the integration with sentinel, deletion works fine.

Sentinel version : 6.2.0

I check for keys with exists() and then trigger delete on the keys.

1. `$redis->exists()` on keys does return true.
2. `$redis->del($key)` -> returns zero all the time.
   I have tried passing keys as an array and also as single key one by one. Neither of them worked.

Before passing the key to `del()` method, I remove the prefixes from them.

In the Predis client interface I do see `delete` method  as  `@method int         del(array|string $keys)`. Not sure what else I could be missing.

Comment: Do you have access to redis-cli from the command line?  You should check the read/write status of your master and 2 replica nodes.

Comment: I am able to add and delete keys manually on redis cli @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: But which nodes are you hitting?  Are you sure that PHP is writing to a write-enabled node?

Comment: I am hitting master node. I am able to delete keys on index 0 from my code. However, on any other index it doesn't work. I think switching to another index is not working as expected. @TimBiegeleisen